# Testing watchOS 1.01 after adding watchOS2 support

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

Everything that I've found so far has been about upgrading, or getting watchOS2 working with Xcode 7. I've seen people say that this should work, but I cannot make it happen.

I had an app with a watchOS1.01 target. I've added a new target, for watchOS2.0. I'm looking for a way to test both of these apps, in the simulator, without having to remove the watchOS2.0 targets each time.

With App + wOS1.01, everything runs fine in Xcode 6. I build the app, run the simulator, turn on the external display, and I can test my wOS1.01

I open Xcode 7, add the wOS2.0 target. Everything runs fine, I can launch the watch Simulator and test my wOS2.0 app.

Now I want to test my wOS1.01 app again. If I launch in Xcode 6, the project will not build. There are dependency errors:

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'macosx' platform
error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'projectdirectory/watchos'.
```

This I assume is because of the new build phase "Embed Watch Content", which is trying to embed something that Xcode 6 doesn't have a framework for, which is understandable.

So, I open the project in Xcode 7. Here, it builds fine. If I build to an iOS 8.4 simulator, the Apple Watch option does not appear in the external displays. If I try to create a new device, iOS 9.0+ pairs only with watchOS2, and any of the 8.x have the paired watch option greyed out.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the correct answer here is to simply remove the WatchKit 1 App and App Extension, and stop supporting WatchOS 1.

All Apple Watch models support WatchOS 2. It is hard to conceive of a scenario where it would be worth the developer overhead to continue to support WatchKit 1, when the number of people with Apple Watches who have not upgraded to WatchOS 2, but who *are* updating to the new version of your app, will be zero or near zero.